# Python os.startfile is not working in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I am using python 3.6 on ubuntu. I wrote a python script to play songs. I have imported os module but it shows an error: **AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'startfile'**

```
            elif 'play songs' in query:
            songs_dir = '/home/mjiabir/Music/mp3'
            songs = os.listdir(songs_dir)
            os.startfile(os.path.join(songs_dir, songs[0]))
```

what is the problem with this startfile attribute? Is there any equivalent of os.startfile()?

Answer (score 2):

`os.startfile` is available for windows only.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) in docs.

You can use `os.open` for that. Visit [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open).

Comment: Then what code should I write to solve this in ubuntu?

Comment: I have tried all flags. But none of them is opening the file. It takes the command and does nothing, just avoids it and asks for the next command. Can you please take a look at the code and tell me if there is any mistake?
        elif 'play song' in query:
            songs_dir = '/home/mjiabir/Music/mp3'
            songs = os.listdir(songs_dir)
            os.open(os.path.join(songs_dir, songs[0]),os.O_RDONLY)

Comment: @JawadUnIslamAbir You can ask another question for that on https://askubuntu.com/ specific to that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem on Ubuntu 20.04 using os.system():

```
import os

os.system('mpg123 sound_file.mp3')
```

But you should first install the package **mpg123**:

```
sudo apt install mpg321
```